# Allow CLI output of service when requested

Tags: c, service, command-line-interface, raspberry-pi4

I am forking a service that controls the fan PWM on a Raspberry PI based on temperature.  Right now the program writes to a file every 1 second the temperature value, fan speed, and time ran.  Because it is writing so little but often and most of the time it is information not being used by anything, I only need the output when asked for.  One option is to have the service make a small RAM Disk that the file is stored on and read from (using 'watch' as mentioned in the original code).  Is it possible instead to have the service run in a way that I can then run a command calling same service that then outputs the values with live updating.  If so, what does that look like code-wise?

Answer (score 0):

in case you're forking the service so you can custom it to your needs. use callback function to expose those info, then you can use this callback pointer to trigger it however you want. i can't provide more details since the question it self lacks details as well xD

Comment: I am just trying to figure out if its possible and what to look into.  What kind of details are you wanting?

Comment: i think if you're just looking for what's possible, so my answer is fine for you, you just need to change the function that expose the data every 1s to be a callback so you can just call it on demand